# Executing .py opens the python shell in cmd

Tags: python-2.7

When I run command in cmd like this: "C:>python my_script.py" it is working, but if I try this: "C:>my_script.py" it opens the python shell in cmd.
Like I typed "python" in cmd..
This happens with any script with extension ".py"
Python is on correct place in path variables.
It started to happen suddenly.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it appears that you want to run python script by double clicking it.

**UPDATE:**
To execute python script without the shell appearing,save your file with **.pyw** extension and select "Open with ***pythonw.exe***"

Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) for documentation help.

On Windows,

1. Right Click on the script and go to properties.
2. Select the option ‘Opens with:’ in General tab, and select the
   python from list, if its not available then browse to the
   installation directory of python and select the python.exe from
   there.
3. Now when you double click on the file it will run automatically.

Comment: My question title is bad, apologizes.. Even if I run script from cmd or double clicked it, that opens the python shell in cmd instead of executing the script with python interpreter.

Comment: @papulic, kindly try the mentioned steps for running the script directly using python interpreter upon double click and let me know if it works or not

Comment: updated the answer, do check if this is what you were expecting

Comment: I tried that. python is allready set as default "open with" program. I set it again, but that doesn't help. I guess something is wrong in registry. I fix the problem with fresh install of python. Although I still wonder what was the problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following 2 commands in the command prompt:

```
assoc .pyw=Python.NoConFile
ftype Python.NoConFile="C:\Windows\pyw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Or if you don't have a `pyw.exe`:

```
ftype Python.NoConFile="C:\Path_to_Python\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```